# How to calculate sub_total and total_price inputs on onkepress event + JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to multiply the `Qty` textbox with `Price` textbox then print the output on `Subtotal` textbox? And then add the grand total of `Subtotal` textboxes and print the sum on `Total Price` textbox with keypress event.

```
<ul>
<li>
    Qty<input type="text" name="item_qty0" id="item_qty0" class="item_qty valid" onkeypress="return calProduct(this);" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
    Price<input type="text" name="item_price0" id="item_price0" class="item_price valid" onkeypress="return calProduct(this);" value="0" autocomplete="off" />
    Subtotal<input type="text" name="item_subtotal0" id="item_subtotal0" class="item_subtotal" disabled="" />
</li>
<li>
     Qty<input type="text" name="item_qty1" id="item_qty1" class="item_qty valid" onkeypress="return calProduct(this);" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
    Price<input type="text" name="item_price1" id="item_price1" class="item_price valid" onkeypress="return calProduct(this);" value="0" autocomplete="off" />
    Subtotal<input type="text" name="item_subtotal1" id="item_subtotal1" class="item_subtotal" disabled="" />           
</li>
</ul>
    <hr />
<p style="text-align:right;">
    Total Price<input name="total_price" maxlength="15" type="text" id="totalPrice" />
</p>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacrajaei/LVFgH/8/)

Comment: It's not a good practice to have same IDs in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is The working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/WLSND/

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
      var total = 0;
    $('.item_subtotal').each(function (index, element) {
      var subtotal = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".item_qty").val())*parseInt($(this).parent().find(".item_price").val()) ;
      $(this).val(subtotal);
      total = total + subtotal;     
    });
    $("#totalPrice").val(total);
```

Comment: Cool yoooo. Working like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var v = this.value, el = $(this);
    if(!isNaN(v)){
        var ov = el.siblings('.valid').val();        
        el.siblings().last().val(v*ov);
        $(this).removeClass('nope').trigger('totalChange');
    } else {
       $(this).addClass('nope');
    }
});

$(document).on('totalChange', function(){
    var sub1 = parseFloat($('#item_subtotal').val(), 10);
    var sub2 = parseFloat($('#item_subtotal2').val(), 10);
    $('#totalPrice').val(sub1+sub2);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVFgH/11/)

I also made some changes in the `HTML` regarding `ID`s